# iCloud, Core Data and duplicates and how to seed initial data?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

i want to check if there's data in iCloud IF there isn't any, Seed new data to it and populate it. if there is data in there use do nothing. also if it could work with versioning .

i have a way to do it without iCloud enabled but i really want to integrate iCloud in my app. As of now i get duplicates when ever i change the version of the app, because then it runs the code for new versioning

here's how i do it without iCloud.

So my question is how do it check if there's any data in iCloud and if it's never use that. if it's older re-write it or something like that. just a way to seed my data when ever i make changes to the plist in hovedmenu and use that.

FYI i'm useing MagicalRecord but i can and properly will use standard Core Data code to for fill it

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ( ![userDefaults valueForKey:@"version"] )
{
    [Hovedmenu MR_truncateAll];
    [self hovedMenu];
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    NSLog(@"running code");

    // Adding version number to NSUserDefaults for first version:
    [userDefaults setFloat:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] forKey:@"version"];
}

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"version"] == [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] )
{
    /// Same Version so dont run the function
}
else
{
    [Hovedmenu MR_truncateAll];

    [self hovedMenu];

    NSLog(@"running code agian");
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    // Update version number to NSUserDefaults for other versions:
    [userDefaults setFloat:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] forKey:@"version"];
}

NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]);

-(void)hovedMenu{
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [NSManagedObjectModel MR_defaultManagedObjectModel];
NSDictionary *attrs = [[[mom entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Hovedmenu"] attributesByName];
NSArray *keyedValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hovedMenu" ofType:@"plist"]
                        ];

for( NSDictionary *keyedValueDict in keyedValues ) {
    NSManagedObject *mObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Hovedmenu" inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    for (NSString *attribute in attrs) {
        id value = [keyedValueDict objectForKey:attribute];
        if (value == nil) {
            // Don't attempt to set nil, or you'll overwite values in self that aren't present in keyedValues
            continue;
        }
        NSAttributeType attributeType = [[attrs objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];
        if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
            value = [value stringValue];
        } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value  integerValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
        }
        [mObj setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        NSLog(@"Value %@ for Key %@", value, attribute);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the examples here.  I have posted a sample app that first checks to see if an iCloud document exists when initialising a new store on a device. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: The iCloud check is done by looking for a directory with the same name as the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquityNameKey` in the iCloud containers `/CoreData` directory.  This check will not work if the device is not logged in to iCloud or has not had network access since the other device created the store in iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video from the WWDC 2012 [Using iCloud with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#227). They also explain how to do exactly what you want and point to other materials about iCloud as well.